# at() not working in function

Tags: c++, string

I believe that I am doing everything right, but the string is not being filled with the characters it is assigned. Here is what I know by testing: random is the correct character, q is the correct int, and s[i].name is a string. I have tried using .at(q) and [q], but nothing is working.

This is my error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at
Abort (core dumped)

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    int q = 0;
    char random = 50;
    for (; random != 32;) {
        file.get(random);
        s[i].name.at(q) = random;
        q++;
    }
    q = 0;
}
cout << s[0].name;
```

Comment: It looks (to me) like you're attempting to assign a `char` to an rval (and the rval doesn't exist).

Comment: According to your logic, `q` can have a greater value than `s[i].name` has characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all the code, it's crashing because name isn't allocating memory anywhere. A call to at requires that there be at least that many elements already allocated for it to work. Try calling push_back instead, that will add the element at the back of the string, expanding it if necessary.

Also, the last line of the for is superfluous, no point in setting q to 0 since it gets destroyed the next line and a new q is allocated on the next loop. Not to mention that with push_back, keeping track of the index with q becomes entirely redundant.
Lastly, the for is making things unnecessarily complicated, use while in this case instead.

Comment: Thank you, simple mistake I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult, because you didn't give us complete code, but if I understand your intention, you should be able to get something like it with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    char random = 50;
    s[i].name = "";
    for (; random != 32;) {
        file.get(random);
        s[i].name += random;
    }
}
cout << s[0].name;
```

If your string is too short, `at()` will throw an exception. Using concatenation like I did should handle arbitrarily large strings.